# HOWTO: Interpret the MSSQL CDC "__$update_mask" field

Tags: sql-server, cdc

Since I had great difficulties how to work with the "$update_mask" field (I don't want to call fn_cdc_is_bit_set for performance reasons), here is the C# code:

- **updateMask** is the contents of the "__$update_mask" field from the CDC "fn_cdc_get_all_changes_[table]" query
- **colOrdinal** is the ordinal # of the column from which you want to get the changed flag (use "n_cdc_get_column_ordinal" to retrieve this value)

The result is the "**hasChanged**" flag. It is set to true if the field has been changed in the update.

Note that this works for SQL Servers 2008 and 2012, but might not work with future releases.

```
byte[] updateMask = this.UpdateMask;
        unchecked
        {
            byte relevantByte = updateMask[(updateMask.Length - 1) - ((colOrdinal - 1) / 8)];
            int bitMask = 1 << ((colOrdinal - 1) % 8);
            var hasChanged = (relevantByte & bitMask) != 0;

            return hasChanged;
        }
```

Comment: I'd reformat this as a question and then place the answer to your question below.  It's ok to answer your own questions.

Comment: btw, I used your approach in a clr to return column names that changed in a comma delimited string.  Worked out great.  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35936/change-data-capture-and-the-update-mask-binary

Answer (score 2):

Just use a [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the ordinal index of the columns that changed. Reverse the mask and add it to a [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), all the array values set to `true` are the changed columns at the corresponding index.

```
byte[] updateMask = this.UpdateMask;  
Array.Reverse(updateMask);
BitArray columnBits = new BitArray(bitmask);

// To match your code sample, you can just check if the column bit is set at the ordinal.
bool hasChanged = columnBits[colOrdinal];

// You could loop and get the column indexes like this as well.
for (int i = 0; i < columnBits.Length; i++)
{
  // If the bit is set to true then the column at the same index was modified.
  if (columnBits[i])
  {
    // Do something with modified column at index 'i'.
  }      
}
```

I've tried to keep the code sample as simple and readable as possible. Remember to check array indexes exist first etc. etc.

Comment: I was stuck on my implementation of this for a long time. `Array.Reverse(updateMask)` was the missing piece! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure on this, but most likely the value in `$update_mask` is the one that `COLUMNS_UPDATED()` returns inside a trigger. You can get details on how to interpret that value here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx

Comment: the format doesn't seem exactly the same as for COLUMN_UPDATED. Instead, the bytes in the updateMask seem to be somehow in reverse order. That's why there is this funny line "updateMask[(updateMask.Length - 1) - ((colOrdinal - 1) / 8)];" in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had procedure with multiple call to function sys.fn_cdc_is_bit_set and even compiling that procedure took few minutes and execution was terrible slow also. When I replaced function sys.fn_cdc_is_bit_set with manual mask parsing it work much much faster.
case when substring([**$update_mask],len([**$update_mask]) - (([ColumnOrder]-1)/8),1) & power(2,([ColumnOrder]-1)%8) > 0 then 1 else 0 end